# Induced voltage in inner coax conductor due to current in outer coax conductor, how is it possible?

Tags: noise, coax

I have been reading "noise reduction techniques in electronic systems" by Henry W. Ott,

on chapter "Magnetic coupling between shield and inner conductor" it's written:

> [image]

> the voltage Vn induced into the center conductor due to a current Is in the shield can now be calculated..

How is it possible to induce voltage in inner conductor *if there is no magnetic field present inside the cavity due to current from outer conductor*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How is it possible to induce voltage in inner conductor if there is no
> magnetic field present inside the cavity due to current from outer
> conductor?*

That lack of a magnetic field immediately surrounding the inner conductor doesn't somehow "insulate" it from the magnetic field beyond the shield. In other words...

It doesn't matter that there is no magnetic field between inner conductor and outer shield; there is a magnetic field outside the shield (due to the current it passes) and, that alternating field surrounds both shield and inner hence, the same voltage that is along the shield length is induced on the inner conductor.

Here is an image of a cross section of a piece of coax.

- The current flow in the shield (labelled copper) is 1000 amps RMS at 100 kHz
- Per metre length (into and out of the page), the shield has 95.9 volts
- The induced voltage on the inner conductor is pretty much the same at 96.3 volts (despite the field intensity between inner and shield being zero (dark blue): -

[image]

Image produced by Quickfield Student edition by me. QuickField is a 2D modeller that assumes the dimensions into and out of the screen are infinite and continuous hence, the voltages recorded in the above picture are "per metre". The model is not very big and, if much more finite element nodes were used the induced voltage would be equal to the applied voltage on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation, 
please help me understand the following, how does inner conductor "knows" or "feel" about outside field? if no flux passing though inner section then how does voltage information getting "delivered inside” ?

Comment: That's a physics question. How does a transformer primary produce flux in the core when the core might be a small distance from the winding? After all there will be no flux between winding and core (if core has infinite permeability) yet, the primary still "feels" the presence of the high permeability core. Why should flux beyond a certain distance be the only flux that "counts" in the coax. All the flux counts of course even if in the immediate vicinity there is zero flux @OleksiyDeliyev

Comment: Well, Maxwell's equations are local, so in order for the inner conductor to be affected in any way, some field has to travel from the outer conductor through the dielectric into the inner conductor.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople utter rubbish.

Comment: What part of my statement is rubbish, exactly? Are you saying that Maxwell's equations actually aren't local, or that the behavior of this system isn't governed by Maxwell's equations, or something else?

Comment: You are thinking of electric fields. i.e. you have completely misunderstood the question and completely misinterpreted maxwell's laws.

Comment: I'm thinking of both electric fields and magnetic fields. Anyway, I'm going to write an answer describing what I think is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible to induce voltage in inner conductor *if there is no magnetic field present inside the cavity due to current from outer conductor*?

First off, I think your observation is correct. Inside the cavity, there is neither a magnetic field nor an electric field. And Maxwell's equations are local, so there's no way that the inner conductor can be affected by the fields outside the cavity. The inner conductor doesn't "know about" or "feel" the outside fields at all; the information about the voltage never gets delivered into the inside of the cable.

All this raises an obvious question: if the inner conductor isn't affected by the fields around the cable, then how on earth does it have a voltage on it?

The answer, I think, is that the "voltage in the inner conductor" is actually in the electric field **around** the cable. When you take a voltmeter and measure the voltage between the two ends of the inner conductor, you're not measuring anything that's happening to the inner conductor. You're measuring that electric field surrounding the cable.

If you somehow managed to stuff your voltmeter into the inside of the cable and measure the voltage across the inner conductor that way, then you'd see 0 V, since there's no electric field in there. But since your voltmeter is outside the cable, the voltage that it sees is the voltage that's defined by the electric field outside of the cable.

Comment: The lack of magnetic field in the gap between shield and inner conductor does not prevent the alternating magnetic field that is beyond the shield inducing voltage on the inner conductor.

Comment: @Andyaka I think I agree completely.

Comment: That's not what you say in your answer.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, I definitely agree that the alternating magnetic field that's beyond the shield causes there to be a voltage between the two ends of the inner conductor (and that voltage can be measured with a voltmeter). The only part of your comment that I don't unequivocally agree with is the word "on," because I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say that the voltage is "on" the conductor. In any case, I edited my answer to try to clarify that yes, there is in fact a voltage there; I'm not claiming that the electric field is causing the voltmeter to read incorrectly.